# Sneak out JSON data from failed JSONP AJAX call

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

When I make this AJAX call

```
var inputText = $('#job-search-field').val(); //for example "CSS"
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/platsannons/matchning',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {nyckelord: inputText}, //searches arbetsformedlingen.se for jobs containing the keyword "CSS".
    success: getAPIResponse,
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
}
```

I get this error in the console

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/platsannons/matchning?nyckelord=CSS. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost` is therefore not allowed access."

When I make this AJAX call (http://jsfiddle.net/MSCbP/)

```
var inputText = $('#job-search-field').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/platsannons/matchning',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp', //jsonp, not json
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {nyckelord: inputText},
    success: getAPIResponse,
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
}
```

I get this error in the console

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

The first error tells me I don't have permission to retrieve the data, right? Since I find no information on how to gain access to the API I'm very interested in getting the response from the second call, which seems to work. Although I get the console error, I see the json data I want in the Network>Response tab in Chrome's dev-tool.

I can't seem to get the JSON data from "success: function()", is there any other way to get it?

Thanks!

Comment: The endpoint for the desired server is not opened to you, correct.  JSON is for same server.  JSONP is for cross server.  Since you are accessing a cross server api, you will need jsonp/CORS requests.

Comment: use console.log to print out the response from the server, or look at the network panel to see what is returned via the request.  You mightve forgot to parse with JSON.parse() or something of that nature.

Comment: Yeah, I use `function getAPIResponse(data) { var theData = data; console.log(theData); }`, but it does nothing. Checking out json parse now. (I'm a noob!)

Comment: if that is the case, then it sounds like you might be sending the wrong data to the server and it doesnt understand it, but doesnt error.

Start by creating an anon-function and attach it to the success.  function(){  console.log(arguments); }   if it still errors there is some issue going on with the servers return value.  Possibly need more keys in your ajax request or something.  contentType/things of that nature.

Comment: Thanks, the anon did nothing too :/ Yes, I am sending the wrong data, and the server should error and not give me any data :) But it gives me data anyway, the problem is that the only place I can see the data is the Chrome response tab. I've tried inspecting the return value of $.ajax(), but I can't find the data there!

Comment: If i can think of a way to grab it ill let you know.  I encountered this before, but i forget how i resolved it.

Comment: Thanks! (Although this seems a bit sneaky, this data is public by swedish law and the very reason they've made this API is to make it public. But the only info available about the API is this: api.arbetsformedlingen.se. Pretty sparse.)